# Not possible to Delete a record on NumberSequenceTable

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, number-sequence

I need to delete a my numberSequence.

But I have a proble, if I try to delete on Table (*NumberSequenceTable*) or on *NumberSequenceTableListPage* when code call a **super** delete method AX goes in loading for soo much time.

I know, it's not good question, but I'm asking if anyone has had these long waiting times.

It's normal ?

Very thank,

enjoy!

Comment: Look at the `DeleteActions` and see what other tables are being deleted. The wait may be a table lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to delete records from that table try to use this method doDelete() by code (NumberSequenceTable.doDelete())
This method does not enter in Delete trigger of the table and will take less time to process.